# PHP Insert Query - Date field 0000-00-00

Tags: php, date

I'm having trouble inserting a record with a date field. No matter what I do, the date field gets stored as '0000-00-00'. The value comes into the php script as a string in this format:
'9/13/2013'. I'm converting to a date using `strtotime`, then trying to insert the record. Here's the code. Why can't I get this to work? Thanks!

```
$my_date   = strtotime($_POST['d']);
//die(date("Y-m-d", $my_date)); //<--outputs just fine if I uncomment this
$sql = "INSERT INTO locations (id, my_date) VALUES ('$id', '$my_date')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/insert-date.html. It doesn't take a timestamp.

Comment: what is the exact data type of the column? have you tried other dates? the month and day might also be swapped

Comment: Make sure the value of `my_date` is correct (i.e. is a valid *SQL value* for the column type) - the value of `date(.., my_date)` is different, and may be more appropriate to pass. Also, *use placeholders*, please.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: let mysql do the date for you with NOW() `$sql = "INSERT INTO locations (id, my_date) VALUES ('$id', NOW())";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm converting to a date using strtotime

`strtotime` returns a unix timestamp (integer), not a date string. You can format it for MySQL before inserting with the date function:

```
$my_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['d']));
```

Alternatively, you can use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class for this purpose.

Comment: Yep, I just found the same solution. Thanks!